# thoughts on this 500 error?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, http-error-500

I cant seem to trace down the reason why I am getting a 500 error on my view.phtml or maybe this is not even the issue?
https://www.********.com/tools-equipment/testers/gold-testers

```
    <?php
/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View
 */
?>

<?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
?>
<?php $config1 = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_home_page'); ?>



<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(($config1=='elite_home_two')) { ?>  <!-- For version 2 -->
   <?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>  <!-- For version 2 -->

<div class="category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1 style="font-weight: lighter; font-size:16px;"><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div> <!--category-title-->

<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check your server error log to get the message related to the 500 error and post it in your question

Comment: [Thu Jul 21 11:27:42 2016] [error] [client 173.00.10.100] client denied by server configuration: /app/etc/local.xml

Comment: that's not the 500 error you probably have another one

Comment: check apache error log

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct this line

```
<?php if(($config1=='elite_home_two'))
```

==> `<?php if($config1=='elite_home_two')` 
I don't see any mistake. If you have PHP syntax error, it may be that was issues

Comment: no change switching out line

Comment: It may be coding timeout when you try to get a huge data in foreach. Try to comment out some lines till your found the issues line

Answer (score 0):

run these two commands on the server:

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

then clear cache

this will change permissions for all files to 644 and all directories to 755

(sorry this couldn't be a comment - not enough rep)

Answer (score 0):

My 500 errors where mostly due to the web user not having acces on the file. Try to chown -R www-data:www-data on the file, assuming that you use apache2.